# Irrlicht rendering basic OBJ

Tags: rendering, 3d-meshes, irrlicht

I have been trying to render a "room" with some basic functions and I found some "bugs".

So at first I have made a "room" out of 6 planes in blender and gave each of them a diffrent color.

[image: Blender room]

Afterwards I rendered it using Irrlicht and here is the first resault :

[image: First resault]

But if I go around the room to see the other sides they start to dissapear:

[image: First Dissapear]
[image: Second Dissapear]

At first, I though it may be due to the fact that i was "too close" or "too far" from the object, or that the object was "too small" but I have tested all those and got the same resault.

So I guess the problem comes from the way I import and load in the mesh, but I couldn't find a way to solve it.

Here is the code for importing the mesh / rendering it :

```
IAnimatedMesh* mesh2 = smgr->getMesh("Sky.obj");
ISceneNode* node2 = 0;

if(mesh2)
{
    node2 = smgr->addOctreeSceneNode(mesh2->getMesh(0), 0, -1, 1024);
    //node2 = smgr->addMeshSceneNode(mesh2->getMesh(0));
    node2->setMaterialFlag(EMF_LIGHTING,false);
}
```

I would like to know why this happens and how to solve it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is probably better to make the room with a cube thinned to the size of the walls, as a plane is only showing one sided, where as a cube shows both sides, (as well as top bottom left and right which can be textured black for faster rendering).
A plane is just not right for a room unless you are only going to view room from inside, then you have to flip the normals in edit mode in blender.

Or as in previous post
The button you are looking for is now called "BackFace Culling" in the materials menu under Game Settings.

OR
see this link
http://www.blender.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=21544&highlight=double+side

Comment: Thnx for the complete answere :) It works xD Even tho I still didn't found the BackFace Culling button ( I might be blind ) Flipping the normals did wonders, And Yes I am working in a game in which the room will be viewed from inside.

Answer (score 2):

This is most likely a normal problem. Since the planes in Blender are not connected (they're just standalone planes, i.e. not connected) Blender can't calculate the normals. You can check if this problem exists in Blender as well by selecting **Backface culling** in the properties panel in the 3d view (`n` key).

Comment: That or he changes the state of what to cull.

Comment: Went into blender, checked textured Solid and I saw the same problem :D, could you also tell me how to fix this? and why can't it calculate normals?

Comment: It's Backface culling, not Textured Solid. (I have no idea what Textured Solid does.) Blender can't calculate normals because it doesn't know which direction you'll be looking at the planes; you can click the corner icon in the Mesh display section ([Normals visualization](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B58OAFDyvbhTalFxZmtwUGoyWVk/edit?usp=sharing)) in the Properties panel to show your normals. To change your normals, select the plane you want to flip and select `w` menu > Flip Normals.